# Why is $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}) \cup \{1\}$ not first countable and the underlying map $f$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I read that given $X = (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}) \cup \{1\}$, we can define a continuous function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow X$, such that:

$$
f (x)=\begin{cases}
      x, & \text{if}\ x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N} \\
      1, & \text{if}\ x \in \mathbb{N}
    \end{cases}
$$

We also define a topology $\tau$ on $X$ as follows (such that $X$ is not first-countable):

$$
\tau = \{U : U \subseteq X \text{ and } f^{-1}(U) \text{ is open in the euclidian topology on } \mathbb{R} \}
$$

Why is $f$ continuous given that there are discontinuities at $x \in \mathbb{N}$? and how is $X$ not first countable?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Could you be a little more precise about the domain and range of $f$?  I'm not sure your function is well defined.

Comment: okay i revised the post and included $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you take $\tau$ to be the topology of $X$, $f$ is continuous by definition. $\tau$ is the smallest topology for which $f$ is countable. If $X$ is equipped with the induced topology then $f$ is not continuous as $f^{-1}(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2})=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2})\cup\mathbb{N}$ which is not an open set in $\mathbb{R}$.

To see that $X$ is not first countable, suppose that $(U_{n})$ is a neighbourhood base of $1$. Clearly for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we can find a function $r_{n}:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow(0,1)$ such that $(i-r_{n}(i),i+r_{n}(i))\subset U_{n}$.

Now we define a function $s:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow(0,\frac{1}{2})$ by
$$s(i)=\frac{1}{2}\min_{1\leq k\leq i}r_{n}(i)$$
and we define
$$U=\bigcup^{\infty}_{i=1}(i-s(i),i+s(i)).$$
Note that $U$ is a neighbourhood of $1$, but clearly for all $n$ we have $U_{n}\not\subset U$. Which contradicts that $(U_{n})$ is a neighbourhood base.

Comment: What if I use the set of open balls centered at $1$ with radius $1/n$ for integers $n > 0$. Should they not form a countable local base at $1$?

Comment: I assume you mean $(1-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})$. This is not an open set in $X$ w.r.t. $\tau$ as $$f^{-1}(1-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})=(1-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})\cup\mathbb{N}$$ which is not an open set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Okay thanks, but just one more short follow up question... If we cannot have an interval $(1-1/n,1+1/n)$ because including $1$ means having $\mathbb{N}$ in $f^{-1}$ which implies it is not open in $\tau$.. how does the set above become a neighborhood of $1$?

Comment: A neighbourhood of $1$ is an open set containing $1$. Technically $$U=\bigcup^{\infty}_{i=1}(i-s(i),i+s(i))\setminus\mathbb{N}_{\geq2}$$ and $$f^{-1}(U)=\bigcup^{\infty}_{i=1}(i-s(i),i+s(i)).$$ Clearly $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open set in the Euclidean topology, which makes $U$ an open set in $\tau$. Basically $U$ is designed to have a small open interval around each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.